# MySql query to group items by 3 elements

Tags: mysql, grouping

i need to separate data in table with next rule:
concatinate values maximum by 3 elements in row, if count is greater than 3 then they are councatinating in next row. I have table:

[image: exists table]

And i want to get this result:

```
one - a,b,c
one - d
two - e,f,g
three - i,j,k
four - l
```

Comment: Does your code compile and link ?

Comment: What does "unable to step" mean? What exactly happens if you try to debug?